# Will a file be read from the beginning if it is a part of a loop?

Tags: java, loops, filereader

For example, in my code, I have something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
    while (file.hasNext())
```

When the for loop goes to i = 1, will it start reading the file at the beginning again, or will the file not be read at all since it was read through at i = 0?

Comment: That depends entirely on what happens in the while loop. If nothing happens in the while loop, nothing will be ever read.

Answer (score 1):

For i > 0, `file.hasNext()` will always return false since you have already read through the file at i = 0 (leaving the file pointer at the end of the file). So, nothing will happen for i > 0.

To read through the file on each iteration of the for loop, you must seek back to the start of the file after the while loop.

I am not sure what the type of `file` is in your question, but take a look at [`java.io.RandomAccessFile`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and its `seek(long pos)` method for how to accomplish this (`seek(0)` rewinds to the start of the file).

Answer (score 0):

It will read from beginning. Does not matter whatever `i` is. Because you are not telling scanner to *not read* until some value of `i` is reached.

Infact, I honestly don't see this loop's significance since you are using `while` loop after this as well. It will just print same file's all lines once.

For example, if your file has these contents:

```
con1
con2
con3
```

and lets say your array size is `4`. Then by your loop, this will be the output:

```
con1
con2
con3
```

If you want to say, start printing from second line, then use some integer for iteration reference and start printing once its `2`. Something like:

int x = 0;

```
while(scanner.hasNext())
    if(x >= 2)
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want to do, do you want to add each word in the file to an arraylist? And then, didn't you use Scanner to read?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("path.ext"));
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    strings.add(scanner.next());
}
scanner.close();
```

was that your problem?

In this case you read each word in the file from start to end

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is incomplete. If file is an instance of `Scanner`, `hasNext` only indicates that there is another token to read, but it does not advance the position in the input stream. Assuming you make a call to `next` in your block, then THAT call will advance, but it won't start again from the beginning unless you reinitialize your `file` variable to point to a new `Scanner` instance.